# Async/await in event handler in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

How can I use async/await in an event handler in react?

I understand the following code is wrong because I'm accessing `this.state` to get the customer code.

```html
<button onClick={handleClick}>Get Customer</button>
```

```
async handleClick() {
    let customerCode = this.state.customerCode;
    let customer = await this.service.getCustomer(customerCode);
    this.setState({ customer });
}
```

Maybe it should be something like this, but I don't think this would work:

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState(async (prevState) => {
        let customerCode = prevState.customerCode;
        let customer = await this.service.getCustomer(customerCode);
        return { ...prevState, customer };
    }); 
}
```

Comment: The two ways make sense for me and works well, do you get some error? Is **this.service.getCustomer(customerCode)** returning a Promise?

Comment: What is wrong in the first snippet ?

Comment: Janathas, I don't think react supports async callback functions in setState().

Answer (score 3):

> I understand the following code is wrong because I'm accessing this.state to get the customer code

What makes you think it is wrong? It seems legit to me.
If you update a value in state like that (mutation) then it may consider as anti pattern, but reading values that way is perfectly fine.

With that said, i prefer to destruct the properties from the `state` or any other object in the top of the function's body:

```
async handleClick() {
  const { customerCode } = this.state;
  let customer = await this.service.getCustomer(customerCode);
  this.setState({ customer });
}
```

I think it's more readable, but both ways will work fine.

**Edit**

Just to clarify, when i wrote both ways will work fine, I meant with and without destructuring. e.g the OP first example and my example.

As for this comment:

> this.state could be stale

In your case it doesn't matter. The only time an updater argument is required for `setState` is when the next state is depended on previous state, which is not the case here.

Comment: Reacts enqueue changes to this.state, so this.state could be stale.

Comment: @rm5432 the update here doesn't need to be atomic, it just needs to happen in the order it was called, so there's actually no problem even if `this.state` does happen to be stale there. If the `setState()` happened to overwrite `customerCode`, _then_ this would be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

If the `customerCode` changes while you are querying, that'll get you into chaos. You could recheck the `customerCode` before doing the state update:

```
async handleClick() {
    const { customerCode } = this.state;
    const customer = await this.service.getCustomer(customerCode);

    if(customerCode !== this.state.customerCode)
       return;

    this.setState({ customer });
}
```

Comment: Same goes for route transition in the middle. you'll get a `setState` to an unmounted component. So this pattern is usually combind with a flag of `isMounted` and checking it before calling `setState`

Comment: customerCode can't change while I'm waiting for the server call because that part of the UI is blocked with an animation. However, that isn't enough because react controls the state and doesn't provide a reliable way to access the state. So, I can't be sure i'm making the server calll with the current customerCode, that's the condition that introduces chaos.

Comment: @rm5432 no, then this is not a problem at all.